# How to start multiple Azure VM at the same time?

Tags: windows, powershell, virtual-machines, azure

I'm trying to use Powershell scripts to start multiple VMs at the same time. I only know how to start one single VM or all VMs at the same time, but in my case, I only want to make change to selected VMs.
Can anyone help me with that? Any help would be grateful.
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Use [Start Roles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn469419.aspx) REST API, if possible. I believe the [PowerShell equivalent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495226.aspx) allows starting only one Role at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following to select only a few VMs.

```
#Get all the VMs you have in your Azure subscription
$VMs = Get-AzureVM

foreach($VM in $VMs)
{
    if ($VM.Name -In "VM1","VM2","VM3")
    {
        if($vm.Status -eq 'StoppedDeallocated')
        {
            Start-AzureVm -Name $vm.Name -ServiceName $vm.ServiceName
        }
    }
}
```